# jQuery if() issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Could someone please tell me whats wrong with the following code? Everything looks good. What I'm trying to achieve is getting the Side-Panel to widen on click, then shorten on click if the value is "Normal".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#widen_btn").click(function(){
        $("#side-panel").css("width", "500px");
        $("#widen_btn").val("Normal");
    });

    $("#widen_btn").click(function(){
        var x = $("#widen_btn").val();
        if(x.val() == "Normal"){
            $("#side-panel").css("width", "250px");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You never reset the widen_btn text!

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this a bit..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#widen_btn").click(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "Normal") {
            $("#side-panel").css("width", "250px");
            $(this).val("Narrow");
        } else { 
            $("#side-panel").css("width", "500px");
            $(this).val("Normal");
        }
    });
});
```

That should work.

It just uses `$(this)`, and makes sure that you change the value of the button to something other than "Normal" when it's not set to 500px.

Here's a 'better' example where we cache the `$(this)` variable, so we're not wasting time recreating the object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#widen_btn").click(function() {
        var $widen = $(this);
        if( $widen.val() == "Normal") {
            $("#side-panel").css("width", "250px");
            $widen.val("Narrow");
        } else { 
            $("#side-panel").css("width", "500px");
            $widen.val("Normal");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you cached $(this) into a variable instead of having to create the jQuery object over and over again.

Comment: You are correct in this assessment.  I'll add an example where it's cached.

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` returns a string.
`x.val()` doesn't make sense.

Also, your first handler always runs even if it's already widened (you need an `if` there).
Also, you need to reset the button text.

Comment: so what would be the proper way to do this

Comment: A) how is this an answer B) How many fanboys follow you around that this has 4 upvotes in under a minute?

Comment: @Sinetheta: It's an answer that forces the OP to understand the problem.  I believe in forcing askers to understand their problems, and people seem to like to upvote me for it.

Comment: @user1238979: What do you think?  `x` already _is_ the value.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#widen_btn").click(function(){
        var x = $("#widen_btn").val();
        if(x === "Normal"){
            $("#side-panel").css("width", "250px");
        }else{
            $("#side-panel").css("width", "500px");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Then `#widen_btn` never has a value of "Normal", without your html I'm just guessing. All I was trying to point out was that you shouldn't bind two click handlers to the same thing, and as SLaks mentioned `x` is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change

```
var x = $("#widen_btn").val();
```

to

```
var x = $("#widen_btn");
```

then

```
x.val()
```

does make sense

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining event handler, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var state = 'Not Normal';

$("#widen_btn").click(function(){

       var x = $("#widen_btn");
        if(x.val() == "Normal"){
        $("#side-panel").css("width", "250px");
        $("#widen_btn").val("Not Normal");
        }else{
           $("#side-panel").css("width", "500px");
           $("#widen_btn").val("Normal");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need to assign two click handlers to the same field for this. Both of those will run on every click so the first will set it wide then the second will (once you fix the if condition) set it back to small.

Secondly `x.val()` doesn't make sense when `x` is already the (string) value so you want to compare `x === "Normal"`. Except that given the `x` variable is only used in that one place you don't really need it at all, you can just compare `.val() === "Normal"`.

So try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#widen_btn").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() === "Normal") {
           $this.val("Narrow");
           $("#side-panel").css("width","250px");
        } else {
           $this.val("Normal");
           $("#side-panel").css("width", "500px");
        );
    });
});
```

Note that within the click handler `this` refers to the clicked element, so I've used `$(this)` rather than `$("#widen_btn")` and cached a reference to that in a `$this` variable. If the button in question is an `<input type="button">` you can just say `this.value` directly.

Comment: none of these are working... Ill probably just wind up using two different buttons

Comment: There must be something else going on in your code. Perhaps you could create a demo of your problem at http://jsfiddle.net to show what's going wrong. You'll notice my answer is very similar to a couple of others, and that's because we (the people answering) all know that this is the correct way to implement this...